# How to declare a Hash/Dictionary of Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I have a program that pushes values into one data structure like this:

```
if(symbolType == "C" || symbolType == "P") // The calls and puts               
    stocks.push({                    
        symbol: symbol,
                undsymbol: undSymbol,
                open: 0,
                type: symbolType,
                expiry: expiry,
                days: days,
                strike: strike

    });
}            
else  // The stock     
{           
    stocks.push({
        symbol: symbol,
        open: 0,
        type: symbolType
    });
}
```

**So this is the key: NOT A STRING!**

```
{
    symbol: symbol,
    open: 0,
    type: symbolType
}
```

And the values of which are many look like this:

```
{                    
        symbol: symbol,
                undsymbol: undSymbol,
                open: 0,
                type: symbolType,
                expiry: expiry,
                days: days,
                strike: strike

 }
```

The problem is that stocks and calls and puts are being put into one collection. Instead, **I want to add the the stocks and their corresponding calls and puts into a dictionary/map, where the stocks are the keys, and the calls and puts get pushed into an array indexed by it's stock.**

At the end, I want to be able to iterate and get the keys and values.

- How do I declare this object
- Index into it to see if the key[stock] already exists, if it doesn't add it with an empty array.
- If I get a "C" or "P", I want to get the corresponding array that holds the Calls/Puts for this key [stock] and push the call/put into the array.

Initially I thought the declaration was something like this:

```
var stockCallsPutDict = {[]}


stockCallsPutDict[stock] = [];
stockCallsPut[stock].push(call);

// Pretty print the dict of keys and its options =
stockCallsPutDict.forEach(function kvp) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Do you have sample data to use for this?

Comment: why not use `Map` ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: Pango - The data is being parsed from a string and looks like the object looks. It is just a string. So a stock string is "IBM, "U". For an option it is "IBM, C", 20170317, 34, 140"

Comment: -Jonathan, that example gets me closer. Thing that confuses me is the key is not a string, but a stock object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If ES6 is an option, you can either build an object yourself or use a `Map`.

Here's some quick code I came up with:

```
const stocks = {};
const addCallAndPut = callAndPut => {
  const symbol = callAndPut.symbol;
  if (!stocks[symbol]) {
    stocks[symbol] = [];
  }
  stocks[symbol].push(callAndPut);
}

const showStuff = () => {
  for (const symbol in stocks) {
    // output stuff using stocks[symbol]
  }
}
```

***OR WITH A MAP***

```
const stocks = new Map();

// basic implementation 
const addCallAndPut = callAndPut => {
  const stockCallsAndPuts = stocks.get(callAndPut.symbol) || [];
  stockCallsAndPuts.push(callAndPut);
  stock.set(callAndPut.symbol, stockCallsAndPuts);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That is clear and I was able to adapt this code.

Comment: I just realized something, the key is not a string, but an object: {
    symbol: symbol,
    open: 0,
    type: symbolType
}  But I need that object to hash to the symbol of the object.

Comment: Why do you want to use the whole object as the key? Doesn't `symbol` suffice in your case? If you really want to use the object, you might want to stringify (`JSON.stringify(symbol)`) to ease lookup in the future.

Comment: Well because I need the entire object later when I iterate over the keys! I probably need to create a class and overload the Hash function. I just never done this in javascript.

Comment: My point was that the properties of a `symbol` are also the properties of a `call and put` which is being stored, so you can get those values when you're iterating.

Comment: Not quite, "type: symbolType" are quite different. For option it is always "C" or "P". But for underlying it could be thirty different values. That's why I need the object later.

Comment: BTW, note the section in the original post "So this is the key"

Comment: Yup - both the `key` and the `value` have `symbol`, `open` and `type` as properties which is why I assumed you don't need to store in both key and value. If you really want to, then your best bet is to stringify the key object using `JSON.stringify` and then parse it when you want to read it as an object using `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to go about this, and the best depends on how the data needs to be processed later, but from your description I'd go with something along the lines of

```
var stocks = {};
var stockCallsPut = {};

// loop over stocks and actions
    if (!(symbol in stocks)) {
      stocks[symbol] = [];
    }

    if (!(symbol in stockCallsPut)) {
      stockCallsPut[symbol] = {};
    }

    if (!(symbolType in stockCallsPut[symbol])) {
        stockCallsPut[symbol][symbolType] = [];
    }

    // accumulated stock json items here
    stocks[symbol].push(new_stock_item);
    // accumulated push/call json items of stock here 
    stockCallsPut[symbol][symbolType].push(new_action);
```

Comment: what is new_action?

Comment: @Ivan it's the json for a call or put

Comment: Ah, gotcha now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure I actually understood what your data looks like, but sounds kind of like this to me:

```
// Not sure if data is an object or array
var data = {
  'one': {
    'name': 'one-somename',
    'number': 'one-somenumber',
    'symbol': 'C'
  },
  'two': {
    'name': 'two-somename',
    'number': 'two-somenumber',
    'symbol': 'P'
  },
  'three': {
    'name': 'three-somename',
    'number': 'three-somenumber',
    'symbol': 'C'
  }  
};

var stocks = {};

for (var name in data) {
  // It sounded like you wanted a call/put array for each object but I'm not sure if that's true since it wouldn't be possible... if so can just divide this part up into it's appropriate place in the if statement below

  // Checking that the property is set on the object, if it is, it uses itself, otherwise it adds it with the call/put arrays created
  stocks[name] = stocks[name] ? stocks[name] : {'calls': [], 'puts': []};
  var type;

  if (data[name]['symbol'] === 'C') {
    type = 'calls';
  } else if (data[name]['symbol'] === 'P') {
    type = 'puts';
  }

  stocks[name][type].push(data[name]);
}
```